# `org-bibtex` is no longer found automatically

Tags: org-mode, org-export, emacs27

I am getting the following warning message since I have upgraded to GNU Emacs 27 on Mac.

I have been using Emacs for `org-mode`. It's my understanding that `org-bibtex` should be a part of GNU Emacs, I don't know why `org-bibtex` cannot be loaded.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/euijeong/.emacs’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, org-bibtex
```

Comment: I have the same issue after fresh installation on Ubuntu Mate 20.04, Emacs 27.1. I have not find any solution yet.
Suggestions? Here is the error message: Compiling file /home/peter/.emacs.d/elpa/org-ref-1.1.1/doi-utils.el at Mon Mar 15 20:23:21 2021
Entering directory ‘/home/peter/.emacs.d/elpa/org-ref-1.1.1/’
doi-utils.el:52:1:Error: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, org-bibtex

Answer (score 3):

In version 9.3 `org-bibtex` has been renamed `ol-bibtex` with all the link-related libraries, see [this commit](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/499c0a50cc4b11e37b91374af23cb27ab8fc20d2)  in the source code repository.

You have to make the same change in your `.emacs`, if you want to support different org versions you have to check the value of the variable `org-version`.

Comment: How to fix it then? Might be silly to ask but I ran into the issue after upgrading to emacs 27 too.

Comment: @lkahtz I updated the answer